# How to properly render fetched api results within an accordion in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, native-base

Hello in my project I'm using accordion of `native-base`.What I'm trying to do is displaying the fetched result from server within accordion. But unfortunately I'm not able to achieve that.Because within the rendering of content and header of accordion I'm doing conditional rendering. So I'm getting nothing within accordion. Following is my code as well as the json response from server. Please help me to figure out the mistake.I really don't know what's the mistake.Please guide.

**json**

```
 [{
    data: {
      course: {
        name: "I. India Economy CourseWare",
        categories: [{
          id: 299,
          name: "Indian Economy Courseware",
        }],
        instructor: {
          id: "1",
          name: "Main Admin",
          sub: ""
        },
        menu_order: 0
      },
      description: "",
      curriculum: [{
          key: 0,
          id: 0,
          type: "section",
          title: "A1. India's Economic Development",

        },
        {
          key: 1,
          id: "2821",
          type: "unit",
          title: "1. India as a Developing Economy",
          duration: 0,
          meta: []
        },
        {
          key: 2,
          id: "2864",
          type: "unit",
          title: "2. Understanding India’s economic transition",
          duration: 0,
          meta: []
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

What I'm trying to show is within accordion I want to display `curriculum title` with `type=section` as accordion `headerContent` and also corresponding title of `type=unit` within accordion content. Following is my code. What I'm getting is this  [![enter image description here][1]][1]   https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wqgZ.png

**code***

```
componentWillMount() {

  fetch('xxxxxxxx' + this.props.navigation.state.params.id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) =>
      this.setState({
        details: responseData
      })
    );
}


render() {
    return ( <
        Container style = {
          styles.container
        } >
        <
        Header
        .. <
        /Header>

        <
        Card style = {
          {
            margin: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#f77a6c'
          }
        } >
        ...
        ...
        .....
        ......
        <
        /Card>

        <
        View style = {
          {
            padding: 10
          }
        } >

        {
          this.state.details.map(detail =>
            <
            ScrollView >

            {
              detail.data.curriculum.map(curr =>


                <
                Accordion dataArray = {
                  curr
                }
                animation = {
                  true
                }
                expanded = {
                  true
                }
                renderHeader = {
                  curr.type === "section" ? ( <
                    Card >
                    <
                    CardItem style = {
                      {
                        backgroundColor: "green"
                      }
                    } >
                    <
                    Body >
                    <
                    Text >
                    {curr.title}<
                    /Text> <
                    /Body> <
                    /CardItem> <
                    /Card>
                  ) : ( < Text > Header < /Text>)}
                    renderContent = {
                      curr.type === "unit" ? (

                        <
                        Card >
                        <
                        CardItem style = {
                          {
                            backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
                          }
                        } >
                        <
                        Body >
                        <
                        Text >
                        {curr.title}<
                        /Text> <
                        /Body> <
                        /CardItem> <
                        /Card>
                      ) : ( < Text > Content < /Text>)} /
                        >

                      )
                    } <
                    /ScrollView>


                  )
                }

                <
                /View> <
                /Container>
              );
            }
          }
```

Comment: Functionality looks fine to me. The error screenshot you shared and the data is mismatching. In the screen shot it is Indian Economy CourseWare Chapters but in the json data it contains just this “Indian Economy Courseware” so Chapters is missing so make sure you are resting with latest code. Functionality looks fine

Comment: Actually it was a typo in my json response when i copied it here. I've edited it.The json response from server is fine.

Comment: Is there any problem in rendering where I've done conditional checking?